# How to get sum of child entries for hierarchical documents?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document of the following form:

```js
{
    "name": "root1",
    "children": [{
        "name": "A",
        "children": [{
            "name": "A1",
            "items": 20
        }, {
            "name": "A2",
            "items": 19
        }],
        "items": 8
    }, {
        "name": "B",
        "items": 12
    }],
    "items": 1
}
```

That is, each level has a "name" field, an "items" field, and optionally a children field. I would like to run a query which returns the total number of items for each root. In this example, it should return (since 20+19+8+12+1=60)

```js
{ "_id" : "root1", "items" : 60 }
```

However, each document can have arbitrarily many levels. That is, this example has two to three children below the root, but other documents may have more. That is, I cannot do something like

```js
db.myCollection.aggregate( { $unwind : "$children" },
    { $group : { _id : "$name", items: { $sum : "$items" } } } )
```

What sort of query will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no way to descend arrays to arbitrary depths using the aggregation framework. For this sort of structure you need to use mapReduce where you can programatically do this:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function () {

        var items = 0;

        var action = function(current) {
            items += current.items;
            if ( current.hasOwnProperty("children") ) {
                current.children.forEach(function(child) {
                    action( child );
              });
            }
        };

        action( this );
        emit( this.name, items );

    },
    function(){},
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

If you do not want mapReduce then consider another structure for your data and do things differently:

```js
{ "name": "root1", "items": 1, "path": [], "root": null },
{ "name": "A", "items": 8,  "path": ["root1"], "root": "root1" },
{ "name": "A1", "items": 20, "path": ["root1", "A"], "root": "root1" },
{ "name": "A2", "items": 19, "path": ["root1", "A"], "root": "root1" },
{ "name": "B", "items": 12, "path": ["root1"], "root": "root1" }
```

Then you just have a simple aggregate:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$cond": [
                "$root",
                "$root",
                "$name"
            ]
        },
        "items": { "$sum": "$items" }
    }}
])
```

So if you take a different approach to mapping a hierarchy then doing things such as aggregating totals for paths is much easier without the recursive inspection that would otherwise be required.

The approach that you need depends on your actual usage requirements.